# How can I change the script so it will not be with a while loop inside Update or using coroutine instead?

Tags: unity, c#

The script is working fine as it is and I don't fell any performance problems and yet I wonder if it's a good idea to run a while loop inside the Update function ?

The idea is to be able to move an object over a curved lines with a lot of positions in any speed.
So I'm calculating how much positions there is next each time and it's working fine I just wonder about the while in the update.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class MoveOnCurvedLines : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public float speed;
    public bool go = false;
    public bool moveToFirstPositionOnStart = false;

    private Vector3[] positions;
    private Vector3[] pos;
    private int index = 0;
    private bool goForward = true;
    private List<GameObject> objectsToMoveCopy = new List<GameObject>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        pos = GetLinePointsInWorldSpace();

        if (moveToFirstPositionOnStart == true)
        {
            transform.position = pos[index];
        }
    }

    Vector3[] GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);


        //the points returned are in world space
        return positions;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (go == true)
        {
            Move();
        }
    }

    void Move()
    {
        Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
        float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        bool stillTraveling = true;
        while (stillTraveling)
        {
            Vector3 oldPos = newPos;
            newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, pos[index], distanceToTravel);
            distanceToTravel -= Vector3.Distance(newPos, oldPos);
            if (newPos == pos[index]) // Vector3 comparison is approximate so this is ok
            {
                // when you hit a waypoint:
                if (goForward)
                {
                    bool atLastOne = index >= pos.Length - 1;
                    if (!atLastOne) index++;
                    else { index--; goForward = false; }
                }
                else
                { // going backwards:
                    bool atFirstOne = index <= 0;
                    if (!atFirstOne) index--;
                    else { index++; goForward = true; }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                stillTraveling = false;
            }
        }

        transform.position = newPos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** This solution assumes the points are far enough apart that it will take multiple frames to travel from one point to the next. There's also some loss of speed when our object reaches the next point. This solution probably is not suitable if the points on the line are extremely close together and we'll be passing one or more waypoints each frame. The original code is probably better in that case.

---

Your move function is more complicated than it needs to be. The while loop is unnecessary. Here's a simplified version of the function:

```
void Move()
{
    float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    Vector3 oldPos = transform.position;
    Vector3 newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, pos[index], distanceToTravel);
    if (newPos == pos[index]) // Vector3 comparison is approximate so this is ok
    {
        // when you hit a waypoint:
        if (goForward) {
            bool atLastOne = index >= pos.Length - 1;
            if (atLastOne) index--; goForward = false;
            else index++;
        } else { // going backwards:
            bool atFirstOne = index <= 0;
            if (atFirstOne) index++; goForward = true;
            else index--;
        }
    }

    transform.position = newPos;
}
```

You can use a coroutine but I don't think it's necessary in this case.

Comment: For some reason now it's not moving on the curved lines at all only on straight lines between the prefabs waypoints.

Comment: @user1741587 Then I am guessing the problem is that I pictured the lines differently than how you have them set up. My simplified version assumes that the points on the line are far enough apart that we won't pass multiple points in one frame. I realize now that your waypoints are probably extremely close together and your object might pass multiple waypoints in one frame. In that case, the `while` loop probably _is_ necessary to keep the motion smooth (you could also use recursion but I believe that's more expensive than a while loop).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `Move()` method into a Coroutine...

```
private IEnumerator Move() {
    //Your code until
    //
    while (stillTraveling) {
        //All your per-step code up until the end of the loop
        ...
        transform.position = newPos;
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate(); // Wait for the physics tick
    }
}
```

Start it running by calling `StartCoroutine(Move());`

Every time there's a `yield return`, control will return to Unity. What you return determines how long Unity will wait before picking up again at the next line.

"Fixed Update" is the clock tick used by the physics engine, hence `new WaitForFixedUpdate()`. Others exist, eg you can return  `null` to wait for the next frame.

As mentioned by DMGregory, you should only invoke this once.

You can do that using a simple boolean to track if it's running. More usefully, `StartCoroutine` returns an objec of type [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html), so you can hold on to a reference..

```
Coroutine mover;
mover = StartCoroutine(...);
```

You can then use `mover` to cancel a running routine...

```
StopCoroutine(mover);
```

See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html for more information

Comment: Remember to start it running only once! A common mistake we see made is calling `StartCoroutine()` every frame in Update, resulting in hundreds of coroutine instances stacking up and fighting over where your object should be placed.

Comment: @DMGregory Good point. I'll add a note about keeping a reference

Comment: @DMGregory using a simple flag for that in the update is good enough ?

Comment: @Basic I did it this way in the link https://pastebin.com/RHMaCih0 but the transform is moving a bit then stop then I set the go flag to true and it's a moving a bit more then stop again and so on. Either the move code is wrong or the using of the go flag in the update is wrong.  Can you show me please how the code should be like after the changes ? https://pastebin.com/RHMaCih0